setHeader('Set-Cookie') not saving the cookie in the browser cookie storage
I try to build a registration route for my app and when sending the cookie to the client the cookie is not being saved in the browser cookie atorage - application/cookies on chrome or data/cookies on firefox. In network tab in Response Headers section i can see the entry
Set-Cookie: cc=bkdbjvsdvs; Path=/; Max-Age=3600; SameSite=None; Secure
and in Network tab in cookies i can see my cookie, its just not being saved to the cookies in application tab for some reason, I have tried the set all properties to all possible values and nothing seems to be working, I don't have any plugins running no ad blocker I have no idea whhy is it like that i've been struggling with this for days. If anyone have an idea why it may be happening please tell me. For contenxt the backend is trpc, but i don't think it matters since i can see the cookie in response headers than it's on the browsers side, i tried chrome and firefox in incognito mode and in normal mode.
